# Can I use Jquery to find an element and set it's CSS width to current-width - x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dimensions

Say I need to correct a number of elements widths by 19px.

Is it possible to `find` elements and set the found elements CSS-width like so:

```
 $el.find( '.ui-content' )
    .css({'width': "parseFloat(found_element_current_width) -19" })
```

If not, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

> As of jQuery 1.6, `.css()` accepts relative values similar to `.animate()`. Relative values are a string starting with `+=` or `-=` to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, `.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )` would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

So you could just do:

```
$el.find( '.ui-content' )
.css('width', '-=19');
```

Comment: hey. didn't know that either. Also very nice. That might actually be the best way

Comment: ok. Going with this, because I think it's best for my need. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

```
$el.find( '.ui-content' )
    .width(function(i, width) { return width - 19;  })
```

Comment: 115k must also imply quick typing besides knowing a lot... :-)

Comment: @frequent More the quick typing :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `css`'s function:

```
$el.find( '.ui-content' )
    .css('width', function(i, w){
         return (parseFloat(w) - 19) + 'px'
    })
```

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly `i` is `index` of selected elements, jQuery iterates through the selected elements internally.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

```
$el.find( '.ui-content' )
    .css('width', parseInt(yourwidth) - 19)
```

Comment: yourwidth was an anonymous variable that can be passed with some value.